# Save query results to a SQL file programmatically

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that generates Insert and Update statements. So I want the proc to save the results to a `.sql` file.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_GenerateScripts]
@FilePath NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(155)
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @GenerateInserts NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @GenerateUpdates NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DataImport') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##DataImport

    CREATE TABLE ##DataImport
    (
        [LongTextId] varchar(150) NULL,
        [Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [Product] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Category] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Subsegment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [DescriptionText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [eDate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [ExpirationDate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UpdatedOn] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    )

    --BULK INSERT ##DataImport from 'C:\CSV Files\file.csv' WITH 
    SET @Query = 'BULK INSERT ##DataImport FROM ''' + @FilePath + ''' WITH 
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
        FIRSTROW = 2        
    )';

    exec sp_executesql @Query;

    /*CSV Data Cleansing*/
    UPDATE ##DataImport 
    set [LongTextId] = NEWID()
    WHERE LEN([LongTextId]) != 36

    UPDATE ##DataImport
    SET UpdatedOn = SUBSTRING(UpdatedOn, 1, CHARINDEX('|', UpdatedOn) - 1)

    DELETE ##DataImport WHERE LongTextId IS NULL;   

    SELECT 'BEGIN TRAN'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        --*,
        'UPDATE [dbo].[Table1] SET' 
    + '  [Code] = ''' + [Code]  + ''''
    + ', [Product] = ''' + [Product]  + ''''
    + ', [Category] = ''' + [Category]  + ''''
    + ', [Subsegment] = ''' + [Subsegment]  + ''''
    + ', [DescriptionText] = ''' + REPLACE([DescriptionText], '''', '''''') + ''''

    + ', [Date] = ''' + [EffectiveDate]  + ''''
    + ', [ExpirationDate] = ''' + [ExpirationDate]  + ''''
    + ', [UpdatedOn] = ''' + [UpdatedOn]  + ''''
    + ' WHERE [LongTextId] = ''' + [LongTextId] + ''';' + CHAR(10) 
    from ##DataImport src 
    WHERE EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM 
                    [dbo].TABLE1 AS dest
                WHERE 
                    dest.[LongTextId] = src.[LongTextId]
            )
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE1] ([Subsegment], [DescriptionText], [LongTextId], [Code], [Date], [ExpirationDate], [Product], [Category], [UpdatedOn]) VALUES (' 
    + '''' + [CustomerSubsegment] + ''', '
    + '''' + REPLACE([DescriptionText], '''', '''''') + ''', '
    + '''' + [LongTextId] + ''', '
    + '''' + [Code] + ''', '
    + '''' + [Date] + ''', '
    + '''' + [Expirationdate] + ''', '
    + '''' + [Product] + ''', '
    + '''' + [Category] + ''', '
    + '''' + [UpdatedOn] + ''');'
    
    from ##DataImport src 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM 
                    [dbo].[TABLE1] AS dest
                WHERE 
                    dest.[LongTextId] = src.[LongTextId]
            )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'COMMIT TRAN'
END
```

This proc works fine and this is how I call it:

```
EXEC [dbo].[Sp_GenerateScripts] 'C:\CSV Files\Text_3.csv'
```

What I need to do is to write the results of the stored proc to a `.sql` file somewhere to a shared folder or local folder doesn't matter. So I have tried to do it in powershell as this

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER-PC -d DB1 -E -Q "EXEC [dbo].[Sp_GenerateScripts] 'C:\CSV Files\Text_3.csv'" -o "C:\Export.sql"
```

In powershell its working but I don't want to use this method. Is there a way I can do this in T-SQL? If yes, how can I modify my stored proc to do this?

Comment: It's easier to go the other way arround, using a client to connect, query and save the results, rather than delegating the dump to file to SQL Server. SQL Server will require an OS user with privileges and that usually means potential security problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the same sqlcmd command from TSQL using xp_Cmdshell. But, using xp_cmdshell comes with its own risks, as it can run system commands. So, care should be taken care before enabling this option using `sp_configure`. Also, if you are planning to use this, it is better to execute using least privileged user context. You can configure proxy account to execute with xp_cmdshell using `sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account`.

[Read more on xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -S SERVER-PC -d DB1 -E 
-Q "EXEC [dbo].[Sp_GenerateScripts] ''C:\CSV Files\Text_3.csv''" -o "C:\Export.sql"'
```

If xp_cmdshell is not recommended as a security practice, alternatively, you can have a CLR stored procedure, especially for this purpose. Again, that requires enabling CLR using `sp_configure`.

Comment: Thanks, @Venkataraman, so can I add this into my stored proc as a parameter?

Comment: @Immortal, yes. you can call `xp_cmdshell` inside your stored procedure

Comment: I am just wondering how I can do this in my case, can you do an example for me please based on my stored proc? Thank you

Comment: I ran this command as suggested but I get null as output and no file is being generated. Any ideas?

Comment: @Immortal, it will be generating in the server machine. not in your local machine. please check in the server machine.

Comment: you are correct. In my case the server machine is my local. I am testing this on my local where sql is installed

Comment: @Immortal execute the statement separately and see if it is working.